# Why are executables OS dependent?

Tags: operating-system

I've seen many people asking this question and mostly the answers I see are like this: "Because the operating systems have different APIs". I don't understand this because when the code is compiled to machine instructions. Why does the API even matter anymore when it's just instructions to the CPU? Let's say that I use CreateWindow function from Windows API. Then that CreateWindow is translated to machine code for the CPU. Then why it can't run on Linux in example? How does the another OS know that I used Windows API since it's machine instructions now. Please explain.

Comment: your program only _calls_ the CreateWindow function. The function itself is part of the operating system (and available as machine code in the binaries of the operating system)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the API even matter anymore when it's just instructions to the CPU?

Because it *isn't* just instructions to the CPU.

> Let's say that I use CreateWindow function from Windows API. Then that CreateWindow is translated to machine code for the CPU.

The **call** to it is compiled to machine code, yes. But that code just calls the function, which is provided by Windows, not embedded in your code. Since Linux doesn't have the same CreateWindow function, your code won't run on Linux.

Executable files for different operating systems also have different formats. They aren't just a block of code that you run starting from the first byte. They have a (slightly) complex structure specific to the architecture of the target OS, so that the OS knows how to load the code from the file, link it to the OS-specific things it needs to be linked to (like the DLL that provides CreateWindow), map its code to code regions and its data to data regions, etc.

So in short:

- Your executable isn't a freestanding block of code with everything embedded in it that it needs to run; it links to resources provided by the OS
- Executable file formats vary between operating systems

Comment: Problem is not really in DLLs which are made by the same machine code as your main executable, but more specifically it resides in kernel API (system call), which are really OS dependent. Plus, of course, executable file format

Comment: @Jack: On Windows, it's DLLs within the Windows system directory (e.g., which you don't ship with your executable) that provide many of these things. For instance, IIRC, CreateWindow is supplied by User32.dll (and presumably its 64-bit equivalent, thankfully I haven't had to deal directly with the Windows API for a **long** time...). \*nix has a different mechanism, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the underlying processor is the same, there several major problems with the type of universal compatibility you call for. All programs make calls to operating system services at some time. I don't think Windoze CreateWindow function is a true system service, but let's assume that it is (If it isn't, it clearly calls as least one true system service and probably several). A system service is written as a wrapper that packs and unpacks hardware registers

Within that wrapper (a gross simplification here) the actual system call is invoked something like

CHANGEMODETOKERNELINSTRUCTION  #SERVICENUMBER

The change mode instruction triggers an exception that causes the processor to invoke a kernel mode exception handler defined by the operating system. The operating system handler jumps to a specific system service by number.

If the Eunuchs system service numbers don't match the Windoze system service numbers (which they will never do because they have DIFFERENT system services), your program cannot have the same behavior.